# Python tkinter get() has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to use each variable in the list in an `Entry` widget, and get the text after pressing a button.

```
self.input_text = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3']

self.activeRow = 3
for e in self.input_text:
    e = StringVar()
    t = Entry(textvariable=e)
    t.grid(row=self.activeRow,column=4,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.activeRow += 1
```

Eventually, I'd like to write the value of each variable in the list to a file but for now, I can't seem to print `self.input_text[0]` after the button press.

```
button1 = Button(text='Write',command=self.__writeNewInfo, width = 15)
button1.grid(row=self.activeRow,column=5,sticky=W)

def __writeNewInfo(self):
    x = self.input_text[0].get()
    y = self.input_text[1].get()
    z = self.input_text[2].get()
    print x
    print y
    print z
```

Comment: So, you want to create several `Entry` widgets, populate their input fields with strings from a `list`, and then retrieve the contained strings?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong thing when creating the instances of `StringVar`. You set `e` to be the item in the list, then overwrite it as an empty `StringVar`. Instead try:

```
for i, e in enumerate(self.input_text):
    self.input_text[i] = StringVar() #Overwrite this item in the list
    self.input_text[i].set(e) #Set the StringVar to take the value from the list
    t = Entry(textvariable=self.input_text[i])
    t.grid(row=self.activeRow,column=4,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.activeRow += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

self.input_text is basically a list of strings. If you want to retrieve something from an entry you need to keep the variable of this entry and call get() on it.

for example:

```
self.input_text = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3']
self.entries = []


self.activeRow = 3
for e in self.input_text:
    e = StringVar()
    t = Entry(textvariable=e)
    t.grid(row=self.activeRow,column=4,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.activeRow += 1

    self.entries.append(t)





button1 = Button(text='Write',command=self.__writeNewInfo, width = 15)
button1.grid(row=self.activeRow,column=5,sticky=W)

def __writeNewInfo(self):
    x = self.entries[0].get()
    y = self.entries[1].get()
    z = self.entries[2].get()
    print x
    print y
    print z
```